# Stuck on a MySQL query with multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am ashamed to have trouble with a MySQL query which should be easy-to-medium... So I hope you'll be able to lend me a hand to get out of this ditch! ;)

Simplifying things, I have 3 tables:

1) publications (colums: idpub (primary), etc etc)
where each record is a bibliographic reference

2) pubs_index (colums: idpub, idindex)
which is a linking table between publications and index_entries

3) index_entries (colums: idindex, name)
which contains the list of keywords available for indexing the pulications

Each publication may be indexed with 0 to n index_entries.

In my query, I want to retrieve the publications that have been indexed with all the keywords 'dog', 'cat' and  'mouse'.

I have tried all sorts of combination of JOINs, with no success so far. Here is my latest feable attempt as an example:

```
SELECT distinct publications.idpub) 
FROM index_entries as index_entries2, index_entries as index_entries3, publications    LEFT JOIN pubs_index ON publications.idpub = pubs_index.idpub 
INNER JOIN index_entries ON bib_index.idindex=index_entries.idindex 
WHERE AND bib_index.idindex=index_entries2.idindex 
AND bib_index.idindex=index_entries3.idindex 
AND index_entries.name like 'dog'
AND index_entries2.name like 'cat'
AND index_entries3.name like 'mouse';
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and have a nice year!

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, you too! :) Actually I'm not really new here, but I lost my previous account details :s

Answer (score 4):

> I want to retrieve the publications that have been indexed with all
>   the keywords 'dog', 'cat' and 'mouse'.

You can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.idpub
FROM
( 
   SELECT *
   FROM index_entries
   WHERE name IN(SELECT name
                 FROM index_entries 
                 WHERE name IN ('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')
                 GROUP BY name
                 HAVING COUNT(idindex) = 3)
) as i
INNER JOIN publications  p ON p.idindex = i.idindex;
```

You might need to modify this query, to get what you are looking for, cause I couldn't understand the other `JOIN`s in the query you posted in your question. But the idea behind this query is this subquery:

```
SELECT name
FROM index_entries 
WHERE name IN ('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(idindex) = 3
```

This will selects only the names from the `index_entries` that has all the three `'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'`. You might need to read more about it, it is called [*Relational Division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: @ArunKillu - No I didn't, I am just a beginner looking for learning just like you :). [**JW**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw) is the [query master](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/query/topusers) here in this site.

Comment: Many thanks Mahmoud! :) I think I'm on the right path to the result... 
Yet, I believe the last JOIN in your query should be something like "INNER JOIN pubs_index p ON p.idindex = i.idindex;", don't you think?

Comment: @user1940642 - Yes, sorry. You are right, fixed now. I was lost in the columns' names in the query you posted. Try it and if anything goes wrong don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Comment: hmmm, I'm testing it and the HAVING clause does not seem to do what it is expected to do... It seems to retrieve only the index names that have two record under a different id :s I'm working on it.